# bash script that will continue execution on a remote server after ssh'ing onto it

Tags: bash, ssh

If i have a script that part of the way thorough uses ssh to go into a remote box, will it continue execution of the script but on the remote box?
like this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@213.219.39.43
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@213.219.39.43:~/.ssh/id_rsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@213.219.39.43:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh root@213.219.39.43
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

p.s. yes, I know, root, I don't like it but that's the user account I was given, so it's the one I'll have to use, thankfully it's a throw-away box so it's not so important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a command to `ssh`:

```
ssh root@213.219.39.43 "apt-get update; apt-get upgrade"
```

Or using a here-doc:

```
ssh root@213.219.39.43 << EOF
  apt-get update;
  apt-get upgrade;
  # more commands here..
EOF
```